# Android to hide/unhide app icon

Tags: android

Can anyone suggest me how to hide and unhide an app icon? After hiding the icon I would like to launch the app if user called on specific number like 1234. How would I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android app without icon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14174993/android-app-without-icon)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android hide/unhide app icon programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114439/android-hide-unhide-app-icon-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

Well, as noted above, the first part of the question is a duplicate of [Android: How to Remove/Uninstall application shortcuts from Home Screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12853443/android-how-to-remove-uninstall-application-shortcuts-from-home-screen) among others.

As for the second part, you need to use a BroadcastReceiver and that has been answered by [Using Broadcast receiver to detect the outgoing calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20464514/using-broadcast-receiver-to-detect-the-outgoing-calls) among others.

Note however, that you need to deploy an intent filter in your manifest, as a BroadcastReceiver is called for all intents.

```
<receiver android:name=".OutgoingCallReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And add a permission as well:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Finally, in Android 6.0 and above, this is a [dangerous permission](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous). You'll need to explicitly ask for it before you can use it. So it's a good idea not to remove the app from the home page before you get it.